# Combining VLOOKUP with SUM

Tags: excel, sum, vlookup

I am trying to `VLOOKUP` column say "B" values from "J" but there are duplicates in B. How can I sum those values in J for same B reference in a lookup formula without doing pivot, etc? As this is a report from a third party and needs to be updated around 10 times a day, doing other steps is very uncomfortable.

So a normal formula bring me first value against first unique reference in B and so on. I would like this to give me sum of all values in J for first reference and so on.

PS: I couldn't post image which would have helped us all.

Comment: You could have uploaded the image to a public file share and posted the link back here. 5-10 rows of sample data is preferred so we don't have to retype the data in your image. Posting the formula you have come up with so far would have at least let us know if your system expected commas or semi-colons for a list separator and what type of data(text/numbers/date) to expect in column B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `Sumif` formula:

```
=SUMIF(B:B;valueYouWant;J:J)
```

And if you want to show "NO VALUE" when the value is not found, add a `VLOOKUP` too. Suppose your search data is in columns A and B of the slave sheet:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(valueYouWant; Slave!A:B; 2; false)); "NO VALUE"; sumif(Slave!A:A;valueYouWant;Slave!B:B))
```

Comment: and i think it has to be a vlookup as i need values on a seperate tab where i've to use this data for further formulas.

Comment: Unless you detail everything you want exactly, I can't help anymore. Sumif is just perfect for summing everything in J that contains the same B.

Comment: Pls see the screen shot on the link above. I'm looking up value of b:b from j:j.

Comment: I'm not sure how the sumif and vlookup will combine as I am already using if(isna) to avoid those errors.

Comment: Sorry...I don't know what you want. Why do you need a Vlookup?

Comment: Because I have around 8 tabs which give me data of same value "B". Which I add once I vlookup the values. Now there is another stage where on each tab column b, I've two or more values of same reference. So when I vlookup, it does the lookup but only give me first value and ignore the rest. I want it to lookup and add (sum) those values from "j" for same unique reference.

Comment: @NFS63  So what you want is an array of all the values from J that have the requested value in B and then later you want to sum up all the values in the array?  i.e. you want it in two separate steps?

Comment: @NFS63  Ok I have reread your comment and I think sumif will do what you want.  If I understand the comment correctly you do something like: `=sum(vlookup("X",Sheet1!B:B,9),vlookup("X",Sheet2!B:B,9),vlookup("X",Sheet3!B:B,9),vlookup("X",Sheet4!B:B,9))` to get the sum.  IF that's true then you just need `SUMIF(Sheet1!B:B,"X",Sheet1!J:J)+SUMIF(Sheet2!B:B,"X",Sheet2!J:J)+SUMIF(Sheet3!B:B,"X",Sheet3!J:J)+SUMIF(Sheet4!B:B,"X",Sheet4!J:J)`  Or do I still not understand?

Comment: Thanks but I am kind of lost here. I've uploaded a file for share on the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzuFuPfITC9Ic2lsWFBnbUE2MVk/view?usp=sharing          now, on tab A2, Column A, there are two values of  "B00XM2Q". I want  those values to be added when the Vlookup for values on Master file.      And currently I am using "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D:D,'US 30D'!B:J,9,0)),"0",(VLOOKUP(D:D,'US 30D'!B:J,9,0)))" in order to avoid those error messages.     Really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is D:D? You cannot use VLOOKUP to search an Entire column, you must search a single value at a time. And you can do just `SUMIF(B:B;D1;J:J)`, `SUMIF(B:B;D2;J:J)`, `SUMIF(B:B;D3;J:J)` ... instead of all that.

Comment: NOT WORKING FOR ME. OR I AM MISSING SOMETHING.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzuFuPfITC9IcndPaWg0bWNuVmM/view?usp=sharing            I've uploaded this excel file for your reference. and it is extremely simplified from what it actually was. If you can help me get values on column B on "Master" tab from "Slave" tab while adding values for same reference e.g reference on A2.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, Thanks and I understand what you proposed but unfortunately this does not solve the issue for me. please take a look at the excel file from link above and hopefully you'll understand. I do not want to do Pivot etc as I'd end up doing pivot's hundreds of times a day and dont really want to get into doing macro's etc either. A simple formula which does vlookup for me from a different tab and if there is a reference occuring more then once, then it just sums the values. I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: There you are. Sumif. Look into the file.

Comment: @Danie I am afraid there is no change to the original file.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15yo3__ROqu84IO5PJprO7GMXKGEfBlpMYwwgMVPsYAE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @Daniel this will save me from a lot of Pivot'ing.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel lookup with sumif works great for my purpose.

Comment: Please see the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzuFuPfITC9IYWRnbzdTeWNrbWs/view?usp=sharing   I would like to have the current formula (without change) working but only with selection of the country name. so for example, when B1 is UK, it will do the rest of the formula for rows with UK in Column "E" on Qty tab. I hope I've explained my question well enough. Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: You're certainly looking for a "pivot table", there is no need to get insane on giant formulas.